# Running a ruby script with options from inside another ruby script?

Tags: ruby, scripting, alias, bash

First, sorry if this is a stoopid question, but I don't know much about ruby.

I have a ruby script I use often, and I use several options, but only the last option is the one that changes, it looks something like:

```
./script.rb -t 50 -n -g -f alwaysthesame.txt -x <URL ALL THE TIME> -Y <OPTIONAL NUMBER>
```

sometimes I add < OPTIONAL NUMBER > at the end, but I only use that 5% of the time.

What I want is to have another .rb script (or maybe an alias [im using linux]), that I can call like

```
./alias.rb <URL ALL THE TIME> <OPIONAL NUMBER>
```

And that would run the first .rb script with all the options.

How can I do that?

Comment: I would suggest doing it in bash since bash is built to do tasks like this and Ruby would be rather slow at it. Not that it really matters unless you are running this command thousands of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link that is informitive about various ways to exec [Ruby Exec](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html)

in alias.rb

```
Kernel.exec("/path/to/script.rb -t 50 -n -g -f alwaysthesame.txt -x <URL ALL THE TIME> #{ARGV.join(" ")}")
```

Running the below would generate the line below it

```
./alias.rb foo bar baz=5
#/path/to/script.rb -t 50 -n -g -f alwaysthesame.txt -x <URL ALL THE TIME> foo bar baz=5
```